# Activate foreign keys after importing a SQlite3 dump

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, dump

When I import a DUMP into an SQlite3 database I manually have to activate the foreign_keys again afterwards.

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

When creating a dump the dump looks like this:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
[...]
COMMIT;
```

When I add the activation command manually it is ignored:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
[...]
COMMIT;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

Is there a way to reactivate the foreign_keys automatically when a Dump is imported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` *does* activate foreign keys.
However, this setting is *not* stored in the database.
You have to execute this pragma for every new connection to the database.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So for every connection I just need to send the `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` at first, to get it running. Good to know.